# Django Calculate Opening Balance sql query

Tags: mysql, django

Can anyone please help transform this view function logic into Django mysql query. with this I can get the results i want but as the database gets bulky, it becomes slower and slower.

The need here is to calculate opening and closing balances.

Models:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max-length=50)
    opening_balance = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Transaction(models.Model):
    item_name = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    purchases = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    sales = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

View

```
def display_balances(request):
    balances = []

    items = Item.objects.all()
    for i in items:
        opening = i.opening_balance

        bal = Transaction.objects.filter(item_name=i)
        for item in bal:
            dict = {}

            opening_balance = opening
            closing_balance = opening_balance + item.purchases - item.sales
            opening = closing_balance
            dict['item']=item.item_name
            dict['opening']=opening_balance
            dict['purchases']=item.purchases
            dict['sales']=item.sales
            dict['closing']=closing_balance
            balances.append(dict)
return render(request, '123/details.html', {'balances':balances})
```

Template

```
{% for b in balances %}
  <td>{{b.item}}</td>
  <td>{{b.opening}}</td>
  <td>{{b.purchases}}</td>
  <td>{{b.sales}}</td>
  <td>{{b.closing}}</td>
{% endforfor %}
```

Output:

```
item    opening purchases sales closing
abc     10      20        10     20
abc     20      10        15     15
abc     15      0         10     5
def     15      15        10     20
abc     5       10        5      10
def    20       0         5      15
```

and so on...

I need someone to help me transform the View Logic into sql query instead of using List of Dictioneries as i am doing. it becomes slow when the database is bulky.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a view something like below and pass whole trans queryset to a template. Then in a template, in looping, you should be able to call `trans_item.item_number.opening_balance` This would be only one call to db.

```
 def display_balances(request):
    trans = Transaction.objects.all().select_related('item_number')
    return render(request, '123/details.html', {'balances': trans})
```

Comment: This is not the answer I am looking for, sorry. What I need is to calculate the opening and closing balance dynamically but not to access the initial item opening balance. getting item_name.opening_balance will display the initial opening balances for each item. what about the rest of the transactions. the same balance will appear every time. hope someone understands what I am saying

Comment: Only thing that I need is the exact View function logic but in a better way using mysql query